# Gmail API Quickstart: Can't install Python Google Client Library

Tags: python, pip, gmail-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to run the [Gmail API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#prerequisites) on my Mac (Mojave 10.14.5)

I've installed the Google Client library as such:

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```

This is the output:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Requirement already up-to-date: google-api-python-client in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.7.9)
Requirement already up-to-date: google-auth-httplib2 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.0.3)
Requirement already up-to-date: google-auth-oauthlib in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: httplib2<1dev,>=0.9.2 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from google-api-python-client) (0.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: uritemplate<4dev,>=3.0.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from google-api-python-client) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six<2dev,>=1.6.1 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from google-api-python-client) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth>=1.4.1 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from google-api-python-client) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cachetools>=2.0.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from google-auth>=1.4.1->google-api-python-client) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: rsa>=3.1.4 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from google-auth>=1.4.1->google-api-python-client) (4.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from google-auth>=1.4.1->google-api-python-client) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests>=2.0.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from rsa>=3.1.4->google-auth>=1.4.1->google-api-python-client) (0.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib) (1.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib) (2019.3.9)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /private/var/root/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from requests>=2.0.0->requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib) (2.8)
```

But when I try to run the quickstart:

```
>python quickstart.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 4, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
ImportError: No module named googleapiclient.discovery
```

Now if I comment out line 4, I get this:

```
>python quickstart.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 5, in <module>
    from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
ImportError: No module named google_auth_oauthlib.flow
```

And if I comment out line 5, I get this:

```
>python quickstart.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
ImportError: No module named google.auth.transport.request
```

I also tried to restart my terminal - and also to restart my machine.

Why aren't any of the Google Client Library modules found?

Comment: is pip pointing to python3?

Comment: `>pip -V
pip 19.1.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why - but perhaps Python 2.x is not supported?

Once I moved onto Python 3.x everything worked:

Installation:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```

Run script:

```
python3 quickstart.py
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install google-auth-oauthlib
```

Comment: You should add some explanation as well.